# Finder doesn't auto-refresh

Tags: macos, finder

If Finder is open on a folder, e.g. ~/Downloads, when I download something it doesn't show up. I have to click on another folder, then open ~/Downloads again to see the download.

I am on macOS 10.13.6 but hadn't noticed this problem until recently.

How can I fix it?

Comment: When did you last reboot?

Comment: I've noticed the same thing, but it predates High Sierra by quite a bit. I've wondered why there's not a "Refresh" button... sometimes the issue can be persistent; even surviving closing and re-opening Finder windows. But it's not consistent either... sometimes it happens, other times not. +1 question

Comment: @Tetsujin yesterday

Comment: Try killing the folder view settings: `rm -f ~/Desktop/.DS_Store`

Comment: This is apparently a long-standing problem that has never been addressed. I suppose the answer is, "Deal with it".  :)